# Meteor.js : return a non-reactive snapshot of a cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, cursor, snapshot

I'm currently returning from a helper a cursor from `Meteor.users`.

**Javascript controller :**

```
Template.rtcCarousel.helpers({
  rtcUsers: function() {
    if (Session.get("rtcSettings"))
    {
      let cursor = Modules.both.query.getRTCUsers(Session.get("rtcSettings"), 20);

      cursor.observe({
        added: ( item ) => {
          if (Session.get('viewMode') == 1)
          {
            // my css animation stuff here
          }
        }
      });

      return cursor;
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML view :**

```
<template name="rtcCarousel">
  {{#each $mapped rtcUsers}}
    <div>
      {{> rtcucard}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The point is that my view can switch between two modes : I want the cursor changes to trigger some cs animation when in mode 1, and to do NOTHING when in mode 2. I mean : I don't even want the view to be re-rendered if documents are added or removed because of the #each that receive my helper.

How do I handle this ? How do I make sure my cursor won't change in mode 2 ? I would like it to return like a non-reactive snapshot at the moment it returns.

I guess I'm going to need some Session value to automatically recompute the helper, and I could then do a tricky thing like fetching the cursor, snapshot the ids, then switch the returned cursor with a new query that matches only this _id's document, and wait for the session to switch back to a normal reactive use case, but it would be terribly tricky.

Isn't there a way in Meteor to snapshot the state of a cursor ?

Thanks for the guidance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible options.

The first one is to use [`Tracker.nonreactive(func)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_nonreactive)

```
cursor = Tracker.nonreactive(Modules.both.query.getRTCUsers(Session.get("rtcSettings"), 20))
```

and the second one is to disable [reactivity on the find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)

```
Modules.both.query.getRTCUsers = function (settings, limit, reactive) {
  return RTCUsers.find({settings: settings}, {limit: limit, reactive: reactive})
}

Modules.both.query.getRTCUsers(Session.get("rtcSettings"), 20, false);
```

Or possibly a combination of both depending on your usecase. I'd say go for the combination, because in your helper, you have `Session` which itself is reactive. And then you are calling a cursor, which is reactive as well. So depending on the context, you may be hit by one or the other in terms of reactivity.

Comment: Indeeds, they both do half of the job, the combination should be perfect for me. Thanks you dude ! :)